# Handle multiple string in Array of String javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I am getting data in array like this, left side are account name and right one are subscriptions.

```
7ef:" 3sdc 12exf"
12ef:" 8ecg"
10ef:" 3ecf 3egf 3elm 3ecf 3egf 3elm "
```

mean 7ef index have 2 strings of data and there is space between both. and 10ef have 6 strings of data.I need this data in form of like

```
7ef:" 3sdc"
7ef:" 12exf"
12ef:" 8ecg"
10ef:" 3ecf "
10ef:"3egf" 
10ef:"3elm"
10ef:"3ecf" 
10ef:"3egf"
10ef:"3elm "
```

As I have to sent it to make its csv file. How Can I do that in javascript ?
Code of creating this is like

```
   foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription) {
    $str=$str.' '.$subscription->uuid;
    }$anew[account[$i]]=$str;
```

EDIT :
Now after reading comments can some one tell me how can I make it like

```
0:" 3sdc"
1:" 12exf"
2:" 8ecg"
```

like I will save account for later and now I want to arrange them all.

Comment: Assuming the target data structure is an object then it's not possible as you cannot have duplicate property names. The closest solution to your expected output would be an array of objects. It would also make more sense to transform the data on the server and give it to JS *exactly* as you require it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  by makking a new field of index ?

Comment: @ephemeral you can't do it JSObject can only contain one unique key per level , so it can't have 7ef:" 3sdc", 7ef:" 12exf" (7ef is already there so next time it will just override the value), use this kind of structure "7ef":["3sdc", "12exf"]

Comment: @SoumeshBanerjee  any soloution as I want to convert this file to csv . So how can I handle ?

Comment: @ephemeral updated the comment and added one solution, hope it helps

Comment: There is no JavaScript in your question; it is all PHP. If you need a JavaScript solution, please provide your JavaScript code where you have problems with. If it is a PHP solution you are looking for (which seems more logical), please modify your question accordingly.

Comment: @trincot check edit

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan kindly check edit

Comment: @ephemeral, that edit makes me wonder what use that list is. You only want a list of UUIDs? That should be peanuts to produce from PHP, but I don't think it will be useful to you, as you cannot derive the accounts from it. Also your edit does not address the issues I mentioned earlier on. You keep writing things in PHP-like syntax (at least it's not valid JavaScript notation) while asking JavaScript. It should be more consistent.

Answer (score 2):

This won't be possible because Javascript Object at same level can have only have unique key, so it will just override the value

SUGGESTED:
use the structure like this

```
{
  7ef:["3sdc", "12exf"],
  12ef:["8ecg"],
  10ef:["3ecf","3egf", "3elm", "3ecf", "3egf", "3elm"]
}
```

code :

```
for (var keys in a){
  for (var data in a[keys]){
    console.log(keys + " : "+ data)
  }
}
```

> a is the var holding the above js object

Comment: i will convert this data in excel file using javascript. At that point  I need to repeat account so what can I do ?

Comment: can you please explain how the rows and cols will be arranged in csv/excel

Comment: like  '10ef'  is account and have multipal subscriptions , So 10ef will come in account coloum 6 times against all 6 subscriptions .

Comment: @ephemeral this code might help you to achieve the goal, and to convert the "a b c d"(spaced separated string into array of strings) you can use the .split(" ") method

Answer (score 2):

Change your PHP code to produce a better structure:

```
$lst = [];
foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription) {
    $lst[] = $subscription->uuid;
}
$anew[account[$i]] = $lst;
```

I suppose you have somewhere:

```
echo json_encode($anew);
```

This will give you the following structure in JavaScript:

```
{
    "7ef": ["3sdc", "12exf"],
    "12ef": ["8ecg"],
    "10ef": ["3ecf","3egf", "3elm", "3ecf", "3egf", "3elm"]
}
```

To output this as CSV, you could do this (assuming the data is in `response`):

```js
const response = {
    "7ef": ["3sdc", "12exf"],
    "12ef": ["8ecg"],
    "10ef": ["3ecf","3egf", "3elm", "3ecf", "3egf", "3elm"]
};

const csv = Object.keys(response).reduce( (acc, key) =>
    acc.concat(response[key].map( uuid => [key, uuid].join(", ") ))
, []).join("\n"); 

console.log(csv);
```